# Android ndk debugging - suspect stack corruption

Tags: linux, android-ndk

I have limited experience in debugging on linux and android. I have ported an C++ application to run on Android. There are quite a few threads(around 15) and i set their stack size to 16384. It crashes randomly when i run the binary. From the stack trace it is not making much sense. Sometimes it crashes within localtime_t.

I notice that the region around SP is all FFFFFFFF. Is it some stack corruption. Or am i exceeding the heap. Any pointer on how to go about debugging it. I suspect memory leaks will not cause such issues.

```
I/DEBUG   (   80):     r0 42b4c358  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     r4 42b24008  r5 00000000  r6 42b241d0  r7 41820d90
I/DEBUG   (   80):     r8 40020cc9  r9 41819000  sl 42b241d4  fp 401b62ec
I/DEBUG   (   80):     ip 42b241d0  sp 41816d40  lr 40046387  pc 40046396  cpsr 60010030
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d0  323320657a697320  d1  6b63617473207465
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d2  6568635320646165  d3  7963696c6f502064
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  bd6bc8e300000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d16 41ca6a16232db22d  d17 3f50624dd2f1a9fc
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d18 41b315d6d5000000  d19 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     scr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #00  pc 00034396 
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #01  pc 0000ecdd  
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #02  pc 0000d228  
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #03  pc 0000d3c0 
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   80):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (   80):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #01  41820da8  41820dd0
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dac  40020cc9  
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820db0  42b241d0
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820db4  4017722c  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+76)
I/DEBUG   (   80):     #02  41820db8  42b241d0
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dbc  42c767d0
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dc0  41820dd0
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dc4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dc8  00000078
I/DEBUG   (   80):          41820dcc  401773c4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+244)
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c338 00000000 00000000 00000000 00013fff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c348 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c358 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c368 000d8a6d 42182ed8 00000000 000000fe
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c378 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c388 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c398 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c3f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c408 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c418 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b4c428 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b23fe8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b23ff8 ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00028ff0
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24008 400539f4 400537ac 00000001 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24018 00000000 00000001 400537ac 00000001
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24028 00000000 00000000 42957d50 42957b78
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24038 42bec4e8 400539a8 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24048 00000001 00000000 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24058 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24068 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24078 00000000 400539a8 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24088 00000001 00000000 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24098 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b240a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b240b8 00000000 400539a8 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b240c8 00000001 00000000 00000000 400537ac
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b240d8 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 429575f0
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241d0 400537bc 42c767d0 0000001e 6d454154
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241e0 00000075 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24210 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24220 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24230 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24240 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24250 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24260 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24270 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24280 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24290 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b242a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820d70 00000000 00000000 00000003 df52773d
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820d80 00000000 42b241d0 42c767d0 40020cc9
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820d90 41820db0 40020cc9 41819000 42b241d4
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820da0 401b62ec 40020cdf 41820dd0 40020cc9
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820db0 42b241d0 4017722c 42b241d0 42c767d0
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820dc0 41820dd0 00000000 00000078 401773c4
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820dd0 41820dd0 42c767d0 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820de0 00000000 df52773d 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820df0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e20 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e30 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e50 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41820e60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020ca8 68096809 bf041a89 bdf0b007 eadef7f3
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020cb8 000330be 0002d276 000330d8 00033064
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020cc8 af02b5d0 b1d44604 1114f8d4 6820b909
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020cd8 46206881 20004788 010cf884 011cf894
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020ce8 6860b168 3fcdf1b0 f64fbf1e f6cf61ee
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020cf8 428861ee 6820d003 46206841 20004788
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d08 0000bdd0 af02b5b0 4605b084 461c4824
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d18 447868bb 4f00f5b3 68006800 46289003
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d28 1114f8c5 bfb84611 4300f44f f7ff4622
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d38 2801ff7f 6868d126 aa02a901 ebe0f7f3
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d48 4818b9f0 9a014621 f7fc4478 4816fd79
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d58 9a024621 f7fc4478 68a8fd73 9002aa02
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d68 99016868 ebd2f7f3 f7f3b950 6800eb4c
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d78 ebd2f7f3 480d4602 44784621 fd60f7fc
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d88 e0022001 f8c52000 49090114 44799a03
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40020d98 68096809 bf041a89 bdb0b004 ea66f7f3
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41818fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41818ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     418190a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     418190b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     418190c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     418190d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241c4 00000000 00000000 429575f0 400537bc
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241d4 42c767d0 0000001e 6d454154 00000075
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24204 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24214 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24224 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24234 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24244 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24254 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24264 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24274 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24284 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24294 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b242a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b62cc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b62dc 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b62ec 00000000 00000001 0001ffff 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b62fc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b630c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b631c 00000000 00000000 4017cb05 4017cb01
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b632c 4017d4b3 4017d5ed 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b633c 00000000 00000000 4004776d 4019e861
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b634c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b635c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b636c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b637c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b638c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b639c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b63ac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     401b63bc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 429575f0
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241d0 400537bc 42c767d0 0000001e 6d454154
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241e0 00000075 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b241f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24210 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24220 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24230 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24240 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24250 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24260 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24270 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24280 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b24290 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     42b242a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816d90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816da0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816db0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816dc0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816dd0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816de0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816df0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816e00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41816e10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046374 447876e4 68006800 0c14f847 f7da4630
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046384 2801fd3a 82e4f040 3020f504 f5002500
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046394 90097054 3020f504 7052f500 f504900a
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463a4 f50030a0 900c704c 30a0f504 794df500
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463b4 70fff649 0a05eba0 eb00a80e f8d40b05
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463c4 b3b801c4 69c96801 b3984788 f826f7d9
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463d4 46594620 f7ff4652 4680fcc1 0f01f1b8
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463e4 990cdb1c 0000f8d9 38016809 45401a40
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463f4 f8d4dd11 b17001c4 69c96801 b1504788
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046404 0108eb0b 0208ebaa f7ff4620 2800fca7
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046414 4480bfc8 f1b8dce5 da160f01 0f00f1b8
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046424 828df040 db0e2d01 0134f894 0f06f010
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046434 e01bd003 f7d92032 4630f82d fcdbf7da
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046444 d1bc2800 200ae284 4445e7f5 0800f04f
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046454 46282d02 db10900b 0b38f10d f04f2000
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046464 f04f0a01 25000c00 e0ac9008 4620a90e
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046364 f5adaf03 b0914d20 f8df4604 f5040604
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046374 447876e4 68006800 0c14f847 f7da4630
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046384 2801fd3a 82e4f040 3020f504 f5002500
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046394 90097054 3020f504 7052f500 f504900a
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463a4 f50030a0 900c704c 30a0f504 794df500
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463b4 70fff649 0a05eba0 eb00a80e f8d40b05
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463c4 b3b801c4 69c96801 b3984788 f826f7d9
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463d4 46594620 f7ff4652 4680fcc1 0f01f1b8
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463e4 990cdb1c 0000f8d9 38016809 45401a40
I/DEBUG   (   80):     400463f4 f8d4dd11 b17001c4 69c96801 b1504788
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046404 0108eb0b 0208ebaa f7ff4620 2800fca7
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046414 4480bfc8 f1b8dce5 da160f01 0f00f1b8
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046424 828df040 db0e2d01 0134f894 0f06f010
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046434 e01bd003 f7d92032 4630f82d fcdbf7da
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046444 d1bc2800 200ae284 4445e7f5 0800f04f
I/DEBUG   (   80):     40046454 46282d02 db10900b 0b38f10d f04f2000
I/DEBUG   (   80):
I/DEBUG   (   80): memory map around fault addr 41816d64:
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41811000-41812000 rw-
I/DEBUG   (   80):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (   80):     41819000-4181a000 ---
I/BootReceiver(  376): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
D/dalvikvm(  376): GC_CONCURRENT freed 330K, 9% free 6452K/7088K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 29ms
```

EDIT: I changed the stack size for all the threads to 64k. The application seems to be running for sometime without any crashes. I am not sure if this was the issue or the actual issue is just masked now.

I have worked with devices with small memory footprint and rtos. Usually the tasks are small and have max upto 16k of stack size. This particaular application is quite big with large function call depths. What is the optimum stack size recommended.

According to this link default seems to be 2Mb
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127602/default-stack-size-for-pthreads